# Can I steal my own checkmark?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

Lets say I was obsessively piling on the hats. If I am the asker of a question (with an already accepted answer), can I self-answer and then accept my own, new answer in order to 'steal' a checkmark?

Comment: Depends on what you put in your self-answer, I suppose. Do you intend to duplicate the currently accepted answer?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No, that wouldn't be in the spirit of things, but say I replaced an outdated answer and accepted it, would I get the hat too?

Comment: It would count towards the hat, yes, but I'm more preoccupied by the ethical considerations here. Could you provide an example of an outdated answer that you would replace?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi [This answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/23228/3610) is outdated, for example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope; in order to earn Marauder, the newly accepted answer cannot be a self-answer.