# Is Lifesaver awarded for self-answering?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

The description of Lifesaver is as follows:

> accepted answer to Tumbleweed

---

If I have a Tumbleweed question and answer it myself with 1 upvote, will I earn the hat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely the answer is "no", judging by [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271032/152859) by balpha, about the previous "version" of the hat in Winterbash 2015:

> The answer was posted during Winter Bash and is not a self-answer.

Same goes for Winterbash 2014 [Naruto hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245790/152859), and Winterbash 2013 [Marauder hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211831/152859).

Comment: Related comment http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312907/weed-eater-hat-not-awarded-according-to-specified-description/312912#comment285481_312912

Comment: @BhargavRao yeah, was going to reference the answer there under "Sometimes your own things don't count", then found a better and much more related answer by balpha. :-)

Comment: Thanks, that was what I thought :D